# Spring & wildfly async requests

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, wildfly-8

When doing async requests to a controller (not using the annotation) I get this error did someone knows why?

I'm using spring 4.0.5 and wildfly 8.1.0

> 16:42:48,621 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default task-20) UT005013:  An IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: UT000029: Channel was
>   closed mid chunk, if you have attempted to write chunked data you
>   cannot shutdown the channel until after it has all been written.

Comment: can you provide me snippet code to reproduce it?

Comment: I am getting the same error, any update on this

Comment: @KrzysztofMiksa Sorry for the delay here is a sample app https://github.com/charlires/rest-api-template

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same exception when I was using Wildfly 8.0 final with Spring 4.1.0, JSF 2.0, and JDK 8.0_u25.  My Server CPU Processing increased 25% each time it occurred.

I resolved the CPU load problem by using Wildfly 8.2.0 Final.

I observed my server for almost 8 days, then I realized this Exception occurs while clients sending a request to the server and Server requires extra time to generate a response. If the user closes his browser window or logs out before getting the response, when the server tries to send the response to the client then the `IOException` occurs.